# Converting FK animations to IK

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have already created a few animations (idle, run...) for a character that I rigged using FK, because I didn't know about IK at the time (I'm very new to animation).

However I recently learnt about IK with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt3-mHBCoQk) and I would like to add IK to my rig because I think it will make further animations easier.
The problem is that when I try to add the IK bones to my rig now, it messes up the previous animations that I had already done using FK, since the IK bones do not have any keyframes to match the animation yet.

This is what the original run animation looks like, vs. what it is now that I have added an IK heel bone. As you can see the left foot is "glued in place" because of the IK.
[image: original animation]
[image: with IK]

Is there a way to "convert" (this is maybe not the right term) my previous animations so that they are not messed up when I add the IK bones ?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Simplest thing to do is just animate the influence of the IK constraint on animations where it's not used.  But yes, you could also delete the IK constraint and copy transforms (temporarily) from foot to IK target, bake visual keyframes, then disable the copy transforms and recreate the IK constraint.